# Recaptcha: detect click

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I am not trying to figure out how to fire a callback when recaptcha is clicked. I know this question has been answered many times and the google doc is pretty clear on how to do this.

What i want to do is prevent the annoying user interaction of clicking the recaptcha and then right away clicking the `Submit` button but having it fail because the recaptcha has not loaded yet. I would like to be able to detect that the user has indeed clicked the recaptcha but google has not responded yet.

This way i can wait a small amount of time and re submit the form without having to show an error to the user.

So far i have tried adding a click listener to the div surrounding the iframe that contains the captcha, but that did not work and I believe it's because the div falls behind the captcha and the click is therefore not detected. Here is the modified google code for clarity:

```
<div onclick='CaptchaClicked()' class='g-recaptcha' style='$Style'data-sitekey='".RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY."'> </div>
<script src='".RECAPTCHA_SCRIPT_URL."' async defer></script>
```

Anyone has any ideas ?

Comment: wouldn't you firing the click be caught as a bot?

Comment: I don't want to fire the click myself. I want to detect that the user has fired a click

Comment: An easy approach would be to disable the submit button, and keep checking for captcha till it gets loaded then enable them to click the submit button

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa thanks! that's a smart workaround

Comment: @NicolaPedretti Do you solve the issue?